# Change my pop-out q/answer event from hover into click

Tags: javascript, events, click

I am working on the faq page of a website and want to show only the answers to save some space on the page. When click on a question the answer should fold out below it, when click again the answer should hide again.

So everything is working fine. The questions are lined up nicely and all looks proper. I have a grey area folding out when hover over the question, plus the question itself becomes bold. Now for my question:

How do i change the hover event into a click event?

I have tried implementing several javascripts without any succes. Hopefully somebody knows a way to do this.

Here is a JSFIDDLE example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lookinggoodtoday/wPVZp/

Regards,
Jeroen

```
    * VRAAG & ANTWOORD TYPE DROPDOWN BOX */
    <style type="text/css"> 
.dropdown-menu 
{
    margin-bottom: 8px; 
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto; 
    width: 910px; 
    background-color:#fff; 
    display:block; 
    display: inline-table; 
 }

.dropdown-menu .menu-item {display: none; }

.dropdown-menu .vraag 
{
    display: table-cell; 
    background-color:#fff; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    font:verdana; 
    color: #777; 
    font-size: 13px; 
    padding-left: 15px; 
    padding-top: 8px; 
    padding-bottom: 8px; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-menu .vraag:hover 
{
    display: table-cell; 
    background-color:#fff; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    font:verdana; 
    color: #777;    
    font-size: 13px; 
    padding-left: 15px; 
    padding-top: 8px;  
    padding-bottom: 8px; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-menu:hover .menu-item {display: table-row;}

.dropdown-menu .menu-item.active {display: table-header-group;}

.dropdown-menu .antwoord 
{
    margin-bottom: 20px; 
    border-radius: 0px 0px 40px;
    letter-spacing:20%; 
    line-height:200%; 
    display: table-header-group; 
    font:verdana; 
    font-weight: normal; 
    background-color:#fff; 
    font-size: 12px; 
    display:block; 
    padding-left: 27px; 
    padding-right: 27px; 
    padding-top: 8px; 
    padding-bottom: 8px; 
    font-color: #777; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    background-color:#f9f9f9;
}

.dropdown-menu .antwoord:hover 
{
    display: table-header-group; 
    margin-bottom: 20px; 
    border-radius: 0px 0px 40px;
    letter-spacing:20%; 
    line-height:200%; 
    display: table-header-group; 
    font:verdana; 
    font-weight: normal; 
    background-color:#fff; 
    font-size: 12px; 
    display:block; 
    padding-left: 27px; 
    padding-right: 27px; 
    padding-top: 8px; 
    padding-bottom: 8px; 
    font-color: #777; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    background-color:#f9f9f9; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}
</style> 
/* -----------------------------------*/

        <!--- VRAAG & ANTWOORD TYPE DROPDOWN BOX  --->

<ul class = "dropdown-menu">
    <li class = "menu-item">
        <a  class = "antwoord"><p>&nbsp;</p> Wanneer een artikel op uitverkocht staat of niet in uw maat leverbaar is betekend dit dat wij het artikel niet meer kunnen leveren. Wilt u het artikel alsnog graag bestellen dan kunt u contact met de klantenservice opnemen. Wanneer u het artikelnummer aan ons doorgeeft zullen wij u op de hoogte brengen of en wanneer dit artikel weer leverbaar zal zijn. </p><p>&nbsp;</p></a>


  </li>
    <li class = "active menu-item">
        <a  class = "vraag"> > Het artikel staat op uitverkocht / is niet in mijn maat leverbaar, kan ik dit artikel nog bestellen?</a>
    </li>     
</ul>

<!------------------------------------------->
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the fiddle. Changed the hover to "active". It acts om mouse click. 
My advice will be to add JavaScript to make your work more easier. 
Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nyxem/wPVZp/1/%60).

```
button:hover { background-color: lime; }
button:active { background-color: fuchsia; }
button:focus { background-color: yellow; }
```

active is used when button is clicked.

Comment: Thank you Nyxem!

That was a very quick response and fix of the fiddle.
As for the effect: Would it be possible the pop-out part stays visible untill clicked again? This in stead of only being visible while holding the mouse button?

Thank you.

Comment: I have added your code and get this: http://jsfiddle.net/Lookinggoodtoday/wPVZp/4/

Still it would be good if it's click to open and click to close. Instead of holding the button to keep it open.

Also on Chrome it works fine for me, but on iexplore its does'nt.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a click event to those elements (this of course introduces some Javascript).

I've edited the jsfiddle to incorporate this. Note that I have included the jQuery library and so will you if you wish to use this solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/wPVZp/9/

```
$(".dropdown-menu").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active-question")){
        $(this).children('li:not(.active)').hide();
        $(this).removeClass("active-question");
    }else{
        $(this).children('li:not(.active)').show();
        $(this).addClass("active-question");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron, that's exactely the desired effect. Now to figure out how to implement this Jquery library since i have 0 experience in it.

Comment: So i have the following line between head tags: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.lookinggoodtoday.com/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> And added your code to the body area between <script> , but it does not seem to work. Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: You should go visit http://jquery.com/download/ and then save the file to wherever you want to keep scripts at. After that, just include a script tag with the src equal to wherever you placed the jquery file in your file structure. This is better than linking to scripts stored on another site.